# How to get load drawable asynchronously from Icon in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to show user contents of notifications that dispatched from this app since the app had been started.
This app is creating for my learning.

It uses LazyColumn Compose but it is very slow in the case that there are many notifications.

Probably it caused by taking long time to load drawable from Notification LargeIcon.
I want to load it asynchronously but I have no idea how should I do it in compose.

The following is a part of code that LazyList Item.

```
@Composable
fun ListElement(notify: Notification) {
    val drawableState = remember {mutableStateOf<Drawable?>(null)}
    Row(modifier=Modifier.height(80.dp).fillMaxWidth().padding(start=10.dp, top=2.dp, bottom=0.dp, end=10.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Column {
            Text(
                notify.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE, ""),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium
            )
            Text(notify.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT, ""))
        }
        val icon = notify.getLargeIcon()
        if (icon != null) {
            icon.loadDrawableAsync(context=LocalContext.current, listener=(Icon.OnDrawableLoadedListener { d -> drawableState.value = d }), handler= Handler())
    // I have no idea how to load asynchronously...
            if (drawableState.value != null) {
                val bitmap = drawableState.value!!.toBitmap()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Image(
                    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = "Icon",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                )
            }
        }}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to reinvent the wheel, and use libraries such as **[Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/)** or Fresco for handling asynchronous image loading.

Here's an example of how to use Coil to load a drawable asynchronously from an Icon in LazyColumn. This will display a placeholder Icon while the image is loading, and then replace the placeholder with the loaded image once the image is available.

```
LazyColumn {
    items(data) { item ->
        val icon = Icon(item.icon)
        val painter = rememberImagePainter(item.imageUrl)

        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null
        ) {
            if (painter.isLoading) {
                Icon(icon)
            } else {
                it()
            }
        }
 }
```

Do not forget to import this library :

```
io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.5.0"
```